# What does $Y_i \perp Y_j | X$ mean in linear regression?

Tags: probability, notation, linear-regression

So I saw in a text book that for linear regression model $Y | X \sim \mathcal N(X\beta, \sigma^2 I)$ we have $$Y_i \perp Y_j | X\ \ \textrm{for}\ \ i \neq j$$ I would like to ask what does this expression really mean?

Comment: Notation is non-standard, so must have been defined in the book. If $Y=(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$ and $Y\mid X$ is normal with dispersion $\sigma^2I_n$, then the notation probably means $Y_i$ and $Y_j$ (with $i\ne j)$ are independent/uncorrelated conditioned on $X$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom, that is what I also thought but isnt in linear regression $Y_i$ and $Y_i$ linearly correlated due to slope?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. The model is $Y=X\beta+\varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon\mid X\sim N(0,\sigma^2 I)$.

Comment: I see makes sense. just one more thing I wanted to ask if  $Y_i \textrm{corr} Y_j | X\ \ \textrm{for}\ \ i \neq j$, meaning they are correlated conditioned on $X$, then how would the model equation you wrote would change?

Comment: If they are correlated, then the normal distribution cannot have dispersion $\sigma^2 I$ (more precisely, the dispersion matrix cannot be diagonal).

Comment: yes true, the diagonal terms will be non-zero and I believe symmetric but I fail to see how can we write that in the form you wrote. Will it be something like$$Y=X\beta+\varepsilon$$ where $\varepsilon\mid X\sim N(0,\Sigma)$, where $\Sigma$ is dispersion matrix with non-diagonal terms providing correlation?

Comment: Yes that is immediate.

Comment: i didnt understand immediate